# Riot.jsにおいて、子や孫のカスタムタグを利用者に意識させずに済む方法

Tags: javascript

当然出来ると思ってたのですが上手く動きません。

Riot.jsでカスタムタグ`<tag-a>`を追加する時、
    `<script type='riot/tag' src='tag-a.html'></script>`
みたいな事書きますよね。
このtag-aの内部で利用する別のカスタムタグ`<tag-b>`のためのscriptタグを、tag-a.htmlに書きたいのですが、誰か方法を知りませんか？
ただ単にscriptタグをtag-a.htmlに書いただけではダメでした。

よろしくお願いいたします。

--追記(unaristさん、ご指摘どうもありがとうございます！)
誤解されそうな書き方だったので補足します。
    `<script type='riot/tag' src='tag-b.html'></script>`
を、tag-a.htmlに書きたいのです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 単に`<script type='riot/tag' src='tag-a.html'></script><script type='riot/tag' src='tag-b.html'></script>` でいいのでは？

Comment: @BLUEPIXY 質問が悪くて、書き方を考えていたところでした(タイトルを編集するかも)。もちろんそれでもいいのですが、この質問の意図している事は「tag-aがtag-bを呼び出している事をtag-aの利用者に意識させたくない」という事です。

Comment: `<script type='riot/tag' src='tag-b.html'></script>` を使わずにtag-b.htmlの内容をtag-a.htmlに書けばいいように思います。

Comment: @BLUEPIXY 別のアプローチでも構いません。カスタムタグの数が増えて、階層が増えて、共有する子、孫、曾孫カスタムタグなどが増えていった場合に、それらを意識しないで済むRiot.jsのカスタムタグの設計のアイデアをもし思い付いたら、ぜひ教えてください。

Comment: [スクリプトの動的読込](http://so-zou.jp/web-app/tech/programming/javascript/sample/script.htm) は使えるんじゃないですか

Comment: @BLUEPIXY ありがとうございます！調べてみます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/29713/18718)で紹介された`riot.compile()`を使う方法がスマートだったのでメモしておきます。
`riot.compile('tag-b.html',function(){riot.mount('tag-b')})`
といった具合で動的に追加できます。

Answer (score 0):

> [スクリプトの動的読込](http://so-zou.jp/web-app/tech/programming/javascript/sample/script.htm) は使えるんじゃないですか @BLUEPIXYさん

のコメントをヒントに、それらしい事が実現出来たので共有します。

カスタムタグ本体のhtmlを非同期で読み込む事になるので、読み込みが終わる前にマウントしてしまわぬよう、`riot.mount('*')`は`window.onload`で行います。

カスタムタグ本体に`<script type='riot/tag' src='tag-b.html'></script>` を書く方法は、残念ながらまだみつかっていません。

代わりに、カスタムタグ毎に取り込み用jsファイルを追加しました。
tag-a.jsでは、上記のスクリプト動的読込を使い、カスタムタグ本体の
`<script type='riot/tag' src='tag-a.html'>`
および、内部で利用するカスタムタグ`tag-b`の取り込みjs
`<script type='text/javascript' src='tag-b.js'>`
をbodyタグに追加します。

tag-b.jsでは、本体のtag-b.htmlと、その中で使うカスタムタグを取り込むためのtag-c1.js、tag-c2.jsをbodyに追加……といった具合で、、、あとはお察しいただけるかと。

あまりスマートな方法ではないものの、上手く機能します。
カスタムタグを配布する場合に役に立ちそうです。

もっといい方法が他に見つかったらぜひ教えてください。