# 動的に読み込んだタグをmountすることができない

Tags: javascript

javascriptなどで動的に読み込む際、よく使われる、下記のようなコードを使っていますが、riot.jsにて、mountができずに困っています。updateやcallbackの実行位置など、試すも、うまくいきません。loadscript自体は動いていて、DOMに追加も確認できています。

30個ぐらい、読み込むべきものがあり、headに全部書いても良いのですが、できれば、必要になった段階で、動的に読み込み、mountしたいと思っています。(いや、30個読めば良いとか、お気づきの点があれば、教えて下さい。)

```
function loadScript(src, callback) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;
    script.type = "riot/tag";
    head.appendChild(script);
    callback();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

自分のやりたいことができました。ソースコードを斜め読みしていると、virtualDomというものを見つけ、事前にcompileScriptsあたりでリストアップされたものをmount('*')することはできても、リストにないものは走査されないのだろうと理解しました。

test.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="riot+compiler.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<test1></test1>
<test2></test2>
<script type="riot/tag" src="test1.tag"></script>
<script>riot.mount('*');</script>
</body>
</html>
```

test1.tag

```
<test1>
 <button onclick='{clicked}'>test</button>
</test1>
this.clicked = function(e) {
 riot.compile('test2.tag', function(){
  riot.mount('test2')
 })
}
```

test2.tag

```
<test2>
<span>{ test }</span>
this.test = 'hello world'
</test2>
```

riot.compileを呼び出すやり方が正しいのか、私には分かりません。今回は、今後コードを書くのに、いま調べておきたいことだったので、問題解決になったと感じています。

http://riotjs.com/ja/guide/compiler/

「タグインスタンスにアクセスする」という項があり、ちゃんと書いてあるじゃないか、という話でした。

Answer (score 0):

手前味噌で恐縮ですが、[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/29629/18718)の質問の回答が参考になるかと思います。
`riot.mount('*')` を、 `window.onload`内で行うというものです。
既に試した上でうまく行っていなかったらゴメンナサイ。

Comment: 事前に見つけていて、試していたのですが、私はうまくいきませんでした・・・。